# Probability of generation of ${\mathbb Z}^2$

Tags: gr.group-theory, pr.probability

What is the probability that three pairs $(a,b) $ , $(c,d) $ and $(e,f) $ of integers generate $\mathbb Z^2$? As usual the probability is the limit as $n\to \infty$ of the same probability for the $n\times n$ square. It is well known that for $\mathbb Z $ the probability of two numbers to generate is $6/\pi^2$.

Comment: It's often called "natural density". It's certainly zero, since the condition implies that $ad-bc=\pm 1$. The analogy would rather suggest to consider triples of pairs.

Comment: Crude numerical experiment suggests an answer of about $0.506\pm 0.001$.

Comment: Interesting; even a proof that the ratio is bounded away from zero would be a good start. Also, in $\mathbf{Z}$, is the density of generating triples known?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know (who proved that) the probability is not 0.

Comment: I said "bounded away from 0", since we don't know beforehand that it converges.

Comment: A quick heuristic that can probably be turned into a proof that it's bounded away from $0$: For any large prime $p$, the probability that $p$ divides both $ad-bc$ and $af-be$ is asymptotic to $2/p^2$ (Either $a=b=0$, or else $b$ is nonzero and $c/d=e/f=a/b$).  These events "should" be asymptotically independent for any finite set of $p$, in which case (since $\sum p^{-2}$ converges) there's a positive probability none of these events occur.  This would mean $ad-bc$ and $af-be$ share no common factor, which would be sufficient to span the space.

Comment: Actually, I'm curious if this can be extended to give the $0.506$ value.  For a prime $p$, let $a_p$ be the asymptotic probability that $p$ divides all three of $ad-bc, af-be,$ and $cf-de$.  I'm not sure if there's a nice closed formula for $a_p$, but it wouldn't surprise me if $0.506$ is asymptotically equal to the product of $1-a_p$ over all primes $p$.

Comment: After switching to C I did $10^8$ samples in the range $[-10^6,10^6]$ and got $p=0.505695$.

Comment: @KevinP.Costello I think your $a_p$ is just $((p+1)(p^3-1)+1)/p^6$.  That gives $\prod_p(1-a_p)=0.5057390639$.

Comment: The 1-dim case suggests that the answer  should involve values of the zeta function.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to Proposition 1 in the paper

G. Maze, Gérard, J. Rosenthal, U. Wagner: [Natural density of rectangular unimodular integer matrices](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2010.11.015), *Linear Algebra Appl.* **434**, No. 5 (2011), 1319-1324, [ZBL1211.15044](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1211.15044),

the probability that $n$ random vectors generate $\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}$ is $$p_n = \prod_{j=2}^n \zeta(j)^{-1}.$$

For $n=2$ this gives $p_2=\zeta(2)^{-1}=6/\pi^2$, whereas for $n=3$ we obtain $$p_3= \zeta(2)^{-1} \zeta(3)^{-1} \simeq 0.505739038$$

Comment: By the way they also consider the case of $n$ random vectors in $\mathbf{Z}^k$ for any $n>k$.  In particular, the "probability" for $n$ vectors to span $\mathbf{Z}$ is $1/\zeta(n)$, and in $\mathbf{Z}^2$ it's $1/(\zeta(n-1)\zeta(n))$.

Comment: Right. I just wrote the statement in the case which is relevant for the question, but their result is more general.

Comment: Well, you extrapolated the dimension and I extrapolated the numbers of vectors.

Answer (score 32):

Let me convert my comments to an answer.  Let $u_n$ be the probability that a triple in $([0,n-1]^2)^3$ generates $\mathbb{Z}^2$, and let $v_n$ be the probability that a triple in $((\mathbb{Z}/n)^2)^3$ generates $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^2$.  Certainly $v_n\geq u_n$, and I think that $v_n$ should be asymptotic to $u_n$.  Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem and the structure of $(\mathbb{Z}/p^k)^2$ we see that $v_n$ is the product of $v_p$ for all primes dividing $n$.  A little linear algebra gives $v_p=(1-p^{-2})(1-p^{-3})$.  Thus, the expected density is 
$$ v_\infty = \prod_p (1-p^{-2})^{-1}(1-p^{-3})^{-1} = (\zeta(2)\zeta(3))^{-1} \simeq 0.5057390381 $$
agreeing with the answer that Francesco Polizzi just entered while I was typing this.

Comment: I talked to Alex Lubotzky about my question and he said that the result can be found in his book with Dan Segal "Subgroup growth", the proof he outlined was similar to your answer.