# Number of distinct directions in the set $\mathbb{Z}^2 \cap B(0,R)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, plane-geometry

We say that non-zero directions $v, w \in \mathbb{R}^2$ are equivalent if they span the same line (i.e. $\exists C \in \mathbb{R}: v = Cw$.), and distinct otherwise. Given a collection $V \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ we are interested in calculating estimates for a number of elements in these equivalence classes.

**Questions:**

1. Given the collection of integer vectors $V(R) := \mathbb{Z}^2 \cap
       B(0,R), R > 0$. How many distinct non-zero directions there exists in $V(R)$?
2. Given the collection of integer vectors $W(R) := \mathbb{Z}^2 \cap
       [-R,R]^2, R > 0$. How many distinct non-zero directions there exists in
   $W(R)$?

One could of course ask these questions in higher dimensions as well. In higher dimensions it would be more interesting (from my point of view) to understand how many distinct $(n-1)$-dimensional hyperplanes such collections of integer vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ span. I equally welcome these higher dimensional considerations too if someone has knowledge to share.

Any known behaviour (e.g. estimates, asymptotics etc.) would be of interest.

Comment: This amounts to counting primitive integral vectors in a centered Euclidean ball. If you consider cubes (i.e., $\ell^\infty$-balls) instead of Euclidean balls, the answer (the asymptotics) is given in this MO answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/303153/14094

Comment: For question 2, it looks as if you're interested in counting rational points of bounded height in projective space.  There is a lot about this in chapter 2 of Serre's *Lectures on the Mordell-Weil Theorem*, in particular Schanuel's theorem (which is more than you need, since it solves the problem over a general number field).

Comment: Actually the above link precisely applies to Question 2 (of course one has to divide by 2 to count the number of directions).

Comment: @MartinBright Thanks for pointing to the reference. I think this is exactly what I am interested in my application, and it also applies to the higher dimensional question as well. Now it seems obvious that the question should have been formulated in the language of elements of bounded heights in projective spaces.

Comment: @YCor I am not sure how the problem at the MO link mathoverflow.net/a/303153/14094 answers to my question? It seems that one gets assymptotically $3/\pi^2 = 0.30369...$ distinct directions (out of all in a given box) which is not quite the same as the constants given for the other MO answer. If you can enlighten me further, it will be appreciated - or maybe I just wrote my original question in a unclear way.